# How to add two mysql table columns to one column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I need to convert this mysql table:

```
FirstName | LastName | Street      | City    | State | Zipcode | Contact Number
----------+----------+-------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------
John      | Doe      | 123 W. Main | Chicago | IL    | 60600   | (312)555-7458
Jane      | Doe      | 321 W. Main | Chicago | IL    | 60600   | (312)555-6628
```

to this table in datagridview:

```
Name     | Address                       | Contact Name
---------+-------------------------------+--------------
John Doe | 123 W. Main Chicago, IL 60600 | (312)555-7458
Jane Doe | 321 W. Main Chicago, IL 60600 | (312)555-6628
```

I tried the code below but datagridview columns 0 and 1 comes up empty

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM people.client";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
myDataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);

//Set AutoGenerateColumns False
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
//Set Columns Count
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

//Add Columns
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "FirstName+ ' ' +LastName";

dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Address";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Street+ '' +City+ '' +State+ '' +Zipcode";

dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Contact Number";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Contact Number";

dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: why can't you alter the Select query and `Select FirstName  + ' ' + LastName as Name` or look at this posting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, " ", LASTNAME) AS NAME,
    CONCAT(STREET, " ", CITY, ", ", STATE, " ", ZIPCODE) AS ADDRESS, PHONE
FROM people.client
```

This selects your two fields and separates them with a space.

Comment: Thanks but the questions wasnt complete enough for what I was looking for. I edited the question.

Comment: You changed the question quite a bit, but I think you can see how to do the same thing I did for "Name" to "Address" to get what you want, right?

Comment: In my answer the last field I used `PHONE` instead of `Contact Name` for the phone because I assume that is a paste error.... right?

Comment: Ok how would I seperate the select query syntax?

Comment: No, its Contact Number but I understand. Thanks alot.

Comment: In your statement you can use single quotes instead of double, or escape them.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Digital Chris.

Mysql Table:

```
FirstName | LastName | Street      | City    | State | Zipcode | Contact Number
----------+----------+-------------+---------+-------+---------+----------------
John      | Doe      | 123 W. Main | Chicago | IL    | 60600   | (312)555-7458
Jane      | Doe      | 321 W. Main | Chicago | IL    | 60600   | (312)555-6628
```

This code:

```
string Query = "SELECT idclient, CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS NAME,"
     + " CONCAT(STREET, ' ', CITY, ', ', STATE, ' ', ZIPCODE) AS ADDRESS,"
     + "`Contact Number` FROM people.client";

MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
myDataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);

//Set AutoGenerateColumns False
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
//Set Columns Count
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

//Add Columns
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";

dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Address";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Adress";

dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Contact Number";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Contact Number";

dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;
```

equals Datagridview Table:

```
Name     | Address                       | Contact Number
---------+-------------------------------+----------------
John Doe | 123 W. Main Chicago, IL 60600 | (312)555-7458
Jane Doe | 321 W. Main Chicago, IL 60600 | (312)555-6628
```